# Hide archived or expired articles in category view for editors/ publishers

Tags: joomla-3.x

In my joomla article blog view i can see the expired and archived articles when i login as a user with editor or publisher rights. When i edit the user rights and set the same user to author, the expired and archived articles are not showing.

How can i set the permissions so that these (expired, archived..) articles never show in the frontend?